Are there any other extension/add-on tools to improve report-writing in SSRS?
Are there any other extension/add-on tools to improve report-writing in SSRS  beside the SSRR by itself also I'm using  visual studio 2019?

To improve or streamline report development I recommend creating a template to base your reports off of. Include a standardized header and footer. If there are a set of parameters you use, include them all. I find it easier to delete want I don't need.

I also use the report variables to store values I want to reuse.

Microsoft released stand alone software packages to create reports. There is one for on-premises and one for cloud.
Microsoft® Report Builder (on-prem)
Microsoft® Power BI Report Builder (cloud)

used only for the Power BI Service
includes a Power Query to refine your datasets

